# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Users_Agencies_UserID"

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-5.0

im using entity framework core 5.0 and i created my one to many relationship with fluent api.
im getting that error when i try to create a new user in my project.
let  me show u to my `User` class:

```
    public class User : Base
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string UserSurname { get; set; }
        public string UserPassword { get; set; }
        public string UserEMail { get; set; }
        public int? AgencyID { get; set; }
   
        public virtual Agency Agency { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(user => user.UserID);

        }
    }
```

and here its a `Agency` class which is related to `User` class:

```
    public class Agency : Base
    {
        [Key]
        public int AgencyID { get; set; }
        public string AgencyName { get; set; }
        public string AgencyPhoto { get; set; }
        public string AgencyEMail { get; set; }
        public string AgencyPhone { get; set; }
        public int AgencyExportArea { get; set; } 
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
    public class AgencyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Agency>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Agency> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(agency => agency.AgencyID);
            builder.HasMany(us => us.Users)
                .WithOne(us => us.Agency)
                .HasForeignKey(au => au.UserID)
                .IsRequired(false)
        }
    }
```

i know,im getting that error `SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Users_Agencies_UserID". The conflict occurred in database "anan", table "dbo.Agencies", column 'AgencyID'.` because there is a no data in `Agency` table. The thing which im trying to do is make that `AgencyID` foreign key optional as a nullable. in `User`  class u can see i defined that  `AgencyID` as a nullable.

do i really need to define that relationship as a one-to-one or zero or is there a another way to do that ?

if i have to define that relationship as a one-to-one or zero,can u show me the way how can i do that.

Comment: What version EF core are you using?

Comment: im using entity framework core 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using EF core  5 you don't need:

```
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
and 
public class AgencyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Agency>
```

All this code is reduntant. You have a standart one-to-many relation that EF core recognizes and configures by default. Remove  all of this code and everything will be fine.

But if you are a student and need to do everything hard way, you can add this reduntant code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Agency)
                   .WithMany(p => p.Users)
                   .HasForeignKey(d => d.AgencyId)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
         });

        }
```

And since you are interested in a configuration, these are another redundant attributes:

```
public class User : Base
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        .....

        public int? AgencyID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(AgencyId))]
        [InverseProperty("Users")]
        public virtual Agency Agency { get; set; }
    }

    public class Agency : Base
    {
        [Key]
        public int AgencyID { get; set; }
         .....
        [InverseProperty(nameof(User.Agency))]
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for ur effort. the main mistake which i was doing is defining that foreign key in a wrong side. it works so well for now,thanks again !!!

Comment: i know efcore 5.0 recognizes most of relationships. im doing a big project thats why i need to be %100 percent sure and i just cant let to recognize every relationship itself. thats why i had to use fluent api. i allready understand your point sir,thanks again !